# ASP.NET + JSON + C#.NET or VB.NET: Problem deserializing date time with JSON WCF WebService

Tags: asp.net, json, jsonp

I'm getting datetime in JSON format as -

```
"\/Date(1261413600000+0530)\/"
```

From **code behind**, I'm using `DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject` method to deserialize data.

Converted data time is not correct.

How to parse correct JSON date time from code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to get the number which is the number of ticks since 1/1/1970. Then you can get the date using the following:

```
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime dt = unixEpoch.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(ticks));
```